# making an activity with a transparent view over incoming call in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a sort of popup on the incoming call screen. this is my code, basically i'm getting the phone number, making another thread and showing it in the log.

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //  Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
    TestAsyncTask myATask = new TestAsyncTask();
    myATask.execute("one", "two", "three", "four");
    //someActivity some = new someActivity();

}
```

I was told i would need to handle.Delay() my method for about 1-2 seconds in order to give my app zoom hovering the incoming call screen and also that my activity shouldn't have a view.

I'm kinda new to android, could anyone  provide an example or a link that relates to my problem?

Comment: Also trying to solve this issue right now. Best I can give you for now is that having a translucent activity is not good enough because then clicks on background will not work.